# hibernate vs hibernate-core maven package

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

What is difference between hibernate vs hibernate-core:

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>3.6.4Final</version>




<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
<version>3.6.0</version>
```

Edit:
It seems that the latter is aggregation of all hibernate modules. Is that the correct and only difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `hibernate` one is just an aggregation. Take a look at its `pom.xml` file at

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hibernate/hibernate/3.5.4-Final/hibernate-3.5.4-Final.pom

Aggregated modules:

- parent
- core
- testing
- testsuite
- cache-ehcache
- cache-jbosscache
- cache-oscache
- cache-swarmcache
- connection-c3p0
- connection-proxool
- annotations
- envers
- jmx
- jdbc3-testing
- cache-infinispan

-- Edit --

As pointed in the comments, the use of the aggregation repository doesn't seem to be recommended, since it's not cited at the official docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/quickstart/en-US/html/ch01.html#hibernate-gsg-setup-mavenRepoArtifacts).

Comment: But hibernate is around 3.6 version and hibernate-core is at 4.3.x version? I mean should not these versions be same(or similar)?

Comment: Well, I think using the aggregation is not recommended. The official docs don't mention the existence of it anyway: http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/getting-started/ and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/ch01.html#hibernate-gsg-setup-mavenRepoArtifacts

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000536/hibernate-artifact-id-hibernate-core-with-version-4-3-5-final-and-artifact-id?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. The referenced link answered the question.